# What are the signs of logic board damage? Is this such a case?

Tags: display, hardware, iphone

So recently my iPhone 6+ fell off of my bed while I was asleep. The screen was slightly popped out and after a simple press back in it worked fine for about another day. I then started to get an issue where the screen would look like snow off of an old television. I can hear calls, I can answer them, my phone vibrates and makes sounds. I can unlock and my phone and text people. But I can't see what I am doing.

I used to be able to hold down the top of the screen near the camera and it would work like normal. I brought it into a phone repair place. He didn't open it up he just connected it to a computer then 30 minutes later told me it was logic board damage. Could he be right?

Is there anything I can do?

Here is what it looks like
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Could well be a loose cable connection—the iPhone has quite a few. Wouldn’t hurt to have a service point open the phone and check the connections.